# Make a globale variable not lazy

Tags: ios, swift, lazy-loading, global, lazy-initialization

I'm building a [library](https://github.com/garnele007/SwiftOCR) in Swift and it has a global variable (global variables are automatically initialized lazy). Initializing this variable takes about one second. My problem is, I want to initialize the variable when the app is loading, so that the user doesn't have to wait later. My current approach is this:

```
My ViewController:

override func viewDidLoad() {

    ...

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), {
        let _ = Foo()
    })
}

My Framework File:

let myGlobalVariable = bar()

class Foo {
    public init() {
        myGlobalVariable
    }

    ....

}
```

But this approach doesn't seam like it is the swiftlike way of doing it. How can I initialize the variable the right way?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no swift way to "when" you should init global vars in your framework , It depends on the flow of your framework , nothing in your framework will be called until it is used , there is no "FrameworkDidLaunch" method, it's a "static" code just like any other classes but in another module , it can even be just a bundle of resources ...

If you want to ensure that someone uses your framework the way you intented to then write it in the documentation and/or add a static method that has to be called before use like "MyFramwork.startMyFramework()" or if you need some info from user like API Key "MyFramwork.setApiKey(_:)" and use it to init global vars and assert if this method was called.